# Setear de forma dinamica un element REf angular

Tags: angular

Dentro de un for, tengo un input a los cuales los quiero poner una referencia elementRef para usarlos mas tarde en TS, como puedo poner dinámicamente el `#` en vez del `[id]` con los valores que me genera el for?

**Actual:**

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of items" >
      <input type="radio"  [id]="superId+ '_' + item.value" />
    </div>
```

**Deseado:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" >
   <input type="radio"  #'_' + item.value />
</div>
```

**Coponente TS:**

```
 @ViewChild('_myValor') myElementoDeReferencia: ElementRef;
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Por qué no con el ID?

Lo que yo haría es agregar a cada input un id, puede ser un label que tenga el item.
Digamos que se llama title. Entonces:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items" >
 <input type="radio" [id]="item.title" #input/>
</div>
```

Luego en el ts

```js
@ViewChildren('input') inputsArray: QueryList<ElementRef>
```

Y para obtener el input que necesitas, ya depende del momento en que lo vas a seleccionar.

Si es con un evento, por ejemplo. focus, entonces:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items" >
 <input type="radio" [id]="item.title" #input (focus)="getElementRef(item)"/>
</div>
```

Y en el ts,

```js
getElementRef(item){
 let toArray = this.inputsArray.toArray()
 let ref: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> = toArray.find(el => el.nativeElement.id == item.title)
}
```

Y así obtendrías la referencia.

Espero te sirva.

Te dejo enlace para que veas cómo funciona.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wzpunr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts